# get_current_user_id() returns 0 another wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two Wordpress sites. I need to sync session. So I have created a page on the second website which returns menu links according to the session.

First Site:

```
$menstatus = wp_remote_get( "https://www.scholarden.com/mentors/?p=8948" );
```

Second Site:

```
get_current_user_id();
```

I have tried:

```
$user_id = apply_filters( 'determine_current_user', false );
global $current_user;  
var_dump($current_user);
```

Both didn't work.

Comment: I don't see any session syncing, also im not sure this can be done, your need more than a simple `wp_remote_get`. Are you storing session in database?

Comment: My question is simple. get_current_user is returning 0 when I call a page from wp_remote_get

Comment: Yeah, because the server has not logged in nor will wp_remote_get store or send session cookies.

Comment: RTM: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get you need to set that up.

Comment: Oh, I see, Got it. Thanks